# how to create enable disable textbox inside gridview

Tags: c#, webforms

```
if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtGLCode = 
       e.Row.FindControl("txtGLCode") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;

    string Enable = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;

    if (Enable == "True")
    {
        txtGLCode.Enabled = false;
        txtGLCode.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a windows application or asp web page?

Comment: @Andile `System.Web.UI.WebControls` - asp.net

Comment: Do you have a separate field in yuor table for true and false? How do you decide?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ASP web page you could do it like this

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
<columns>
  <asp:templatefield headertext="TextBox">
   <itemtemplate>
    <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ColumnName")%>' />
   </itemtemplate>
  </asp:templatefield>  
</columns>
```

Where column name is the column from the datatable that you are binding to you GridView. You can the reference the TextBox control using the id from code behind. To hide it you can do it in two ways, one is from the markup which is done like below

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
<columns>
  <asp:templatefield headertext="TextBox">
   <itemtemplate>
    <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ColumnName")%>' Visible='<%# iif(Expression, true, false) %>'/>
   </itemtemplate>
  </asp:templatefield>  
</columns>
```

Expression: Will be what you want to the textbox to be shown when it true. I hope this gives you an insight.

Comment: No worries please share you markup code and code behind so I can have a look

Comment: protected void XbrlGLGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtGLCode = e.Row.FindControl("txtGLCode") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
            string Enable = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
            if (Enable == "True")
            {
                txtGLCode.Enabled = false;
                txtGLCode.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
}

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="XbrlGLGrid" runat="server" Width="500px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="XbrlGLGrid_RowDataBound" ><Columns>                         
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GL Code" >
   <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtGLCode" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="tooltip" Width="100px" EnableViewState="true"ToolTip="For Help, Double Click or Press F2" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="True"OnTextChanged="txtGLCode_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>                   
 </asp:TemplateField><asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Value"/>